# change background according to user preference

Tags: html, css

Hi i would like to have like 5 backgrounds to choose from and a user can just click on a box with a thumbnail of each and the site will dynamically change the background.  How would I do this? thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow @Tuan Dang! If you're unsure about what and how you should ask a question, take a peek at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 

In order for us to help you with your problem, you need to include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, maybe you need to learn first about html and javascript.
First of all, you must prepare html structure like this:

```
 <div class="box" data-bg="img1.jpg"></div>
 <div class="box" data-bg="img2.jpg"></div>
 <div class="box" data-bg="img3.jpg"></div>
 <div class="box" data-bg="img4.jpg"></div>
 <div class="box" data-bg="img5.jpg"></div>
```

A CSS example to make it works :

```
 .box {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color:blue;
 }
```

The javascript

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box"); // get all elements
 for(var i in elements) { // loop through them
     elements[i].click(function(e) {  // handle click
          document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage = this.dataset().bg;  //change background
     });
 }
```

Comment: O wow thank you. I understand the css and html part of that. I definitely need to go familiarize my self with what the JavaScript part is saying. Thanks!